# How to provide a `FutureOr<Null>` in a `catchError()` in a `FlutterLogin` with Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to wire up Firebase auth method to the `FlutterLogin` callback as follows:

```dart
Future<String?> _authUser(BuildContext context, LoginData data) {
    debugPrint('Name: ${data.name}, Password: ${data.password}');

    return auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: data.name, password: data.password)
        .then((credential) {

      return null;

    }).catchError((e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        debugPrint('The password provided is too weak.');
        return Future.error(e);
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        return 'The account already exists for that email.';
      } else {
        debugPrint(e.toString());  // <==== Where I get the exception
        return Future.error(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

I get the exception 'user-not-found' with is normal as the user does not exists yet. But how I can send the error back to FlutterLogin, as I am said to provide a `FutureOr<null>`?:

> A value of type 'Future' can't be returned by the 'onError' handler because it must be assignable to 'FutureOr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The error occurred because returning invalid type in `cathcError()`.

> Your in your code `Future.error()` returns `Future<dynamic>` instaed of `FutureOr<String?>`

> `Future.catchError()` constructor returns `Future<T>`. You can see this in the image.

[image: The method in Future class]

> `Future.error()` is a factory constructor in `Future` class and it returns private future instance with generic (`T`) type. You can see this in the image again.

[image: The factory constructor in Future class]

> So give generic type `String?` and `String?` property to `Future<T>.error()`.
> Fixed code:

```
Future<String?> _authUser(BuildContext context, LoginData data) {
debugPrint('Name: ${data.name}, Password: ${data.password}');

return auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: data.name, password: data.password)
    .then((credential) {

  return null;

}).catchError((e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    debugPrint('The password provided is too weak.');
    return Future.error(e);
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    return 'The account already exists for that email.';
  } else {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
    return Future<String?>.error(e.code); // String? generic type gived.
  } 
});
```

}